# Strange behaviour using Popen inside threads

Tags: python, subprocess, python-multithreading

Here's the catch, I'm running a python3 script that starts 4 threads. Each thread starts another script (in python2) 8 times.

I want thoses calls to wait for the end before recalling the script that is why I'm using p.communicate() and p.wait().

However I'm noticing that the threads simply ignore the p.communicate() and p.wait() and keep calling popen without waiting.

Here are simplified versions of my scripts that reproduce the behaviour.

**Python3 script**

```
import threading
import threading
def run_thread(nb_processes):
    for index in range(nb_processes):
      print("Starting {}".format(index))
      call = 'python2 testwait.py'
      p = subprocess.Popen(call.split(), shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
      p.communicate()
      p.wait()


def main():
    nb_concurrent_threads = 4
    nb_process_to_call_by_thread = 8
    threads = []
    for thread in range(nb_concurrent_threads):
        print("Thread : {}".format(thread))
        t = threading.Thread(target=run_thread, args=[nb_process_to_call_by_thread])
        threads.append(t)
        t.start()
    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()
        print(thread.stdout)
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Python2 script**

```
import time
for i in range(0,100):
  print(i)
  time.sleep(1)
```

Any ideas on why this is happening ? I already tried replacing popen with call or check_call without any sucess.

Edit : the "Starting 2,3,..." are printed immediately after starting the script however there sould be more time since the python2 script is supposed to take a while to run.

```
Thread : 0                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Starting 0                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Thread : 1                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Starting 0                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Thread : 2                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Starting 0                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Thread : 3                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Starting 0                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Starting 1                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Starting 1                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Starting 1                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Starting 2                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Starting 2                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Starting 2                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Starting 3                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Starting 3                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Starting 3                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Starting 4                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Starting 4                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Starting 4                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Starting 5                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Starting 5                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Starting 5                                                                                                                                                                                                         
[.....]
```

Comment: _Each thread starts another script (in python2) 8 times._ I'm curious, is there no better way to do this?

Comment: I copied my your code to my local machine and was not able to reproduce the behavior your describe. How are you determining that it's not waiting? Have you tried printing stdout and stderr? Is `testwait.py` in your current working directory?

Comment: Well my example is a simplification. I have to run the same script with different parameters each time (script in python2 takes a while to run that's why I want to multi-thread). The script in python3 is in charge of chosing the parameters. I haven't found a better way but I'm open to any idea.

Comment: @jordanm Simply because there should be more time between the "Starting 1" and "Starting 2" because the python2 script is supposed to take a while.

Comment: @MerkleDaamgard that doesn't mean that `communicate()` is not working properly. Most likely your command is erroring and immediately exiting. I'm putting my money on "testwait.py" not being inside your current working directory.

Comment: @jordanm Well in the real use case, the python2 scripts outputs to a log_file. Thus I can clearly see that the script is starting to much processes. Plus all the outputs inside the log are as expected.

Comment: So the script in the question isn't the one you are testing with? Are you able to reproduce the issue with the script in the question? I am not

Comment: @jordanm The scripts that I provided reproduce the behaviour that I witness with my original scripts. I can't figure out why it does not do the same on a different setup (I use Ubuntu and python 3.5.6 and python2.7.2)

Answer (score 0):

As jordanm stated, "my money is on testwait.py" well send me your btc address you were right. My log file didn't captured stderr... I checked the return code of the script with p.poll() and it was indeed 1.

Thanks !